# Sencha Touch JsonP Callback doesn't recognise Ext object

Tags: ajax, json, extjs, sencha-touch

I am using Sencha Touch's Ext.data.JsonP.request call in the following manner:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url: 'php/apiCustomer.php',
    callbackKey: 'callback',
    scope: this,
    params: {
        action:   'AttemptLogin',
        email:    name,
        password: password,
        format:   'json'
    },
    success: function(result, request) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

The response looks like this:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.callback1({...})
```

Under normal circumstances, this works exactly correctly. However, when running the built production code, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'JsonP' of undefined
```

I did my own sleuthing and discovered that when the callback is evaluated, this is all that is known of the 'Ext' object:

```
Ext.blink
Ext.microloaded
Ext.filterPlatform
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

EDIT:

The contents of my app.json file are:

```
{
    /**
     * The application's namespace, used by Sencha Command to generate classes
     */
    "name": "MyApp",

    /**
     * The file path to this application's front HTML document, relative to this app.json file
     */
    "indexHtmlPath": "index.html",

    /**
     * The absolute URL to this application in development environment, i.e: the URL to run this application
     * on your web browser during development, e.g: "http://localhost/myapp/index.html".
     *
     * This value is needed when build to resolve your application's dependencies if it requires server-side resources
     * that are not accessible via file system protocol.
     */
    "url": null,

    /**
     * List of all JavaScript assets in the right execution order.
     * Each item is an object with the following format:
     *      {
     *          "path": "path/to/script.js" // Path to file, if local file it must be relative to this app.json file
     *          "remote": true              // (Optional)
     *                                      // - Defaults to undefined (falsey) to signal a local file which will be copied
     *                                      // - Specify true if this file is a remote file which will not to be copied
     *          "update": "delta"           // (Optional)
     *                                      //  - If not specified, this file will only be loaded once, and
     *                                      //    cached inside localStorage until this value is changed.
     *                                      //  - "delta" to enable over-the-air delta update for this file
     *                                      //  - "full" means full update will be made when this file changes
     *          "x-bootstrap": true         // (Optional)
     *                                      // Indicates a development mode only dependency.  
     *                                      // These files will not be copied into the build directory or referenced
     *                                      // in the generate app.json manifest for the micro loader.
     *
     *      }
     */
    "js": [
        {
            "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js",
            "x-bootstrap": true
        },
        {
            "path": "bootstrap.js",
            "x-bootstrap": true
        },
        {
            "path": "app.js",
            "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
            "update": "delta"
        }
    ],

    /**
     * List of all CSS assets in the right inclusion order.
     * Each item is an object with the following format:
     *      {
     *          "path": "path/to/item.css" // Path to file, if local file it must be relative to this app.json file
     *          "remote": true             // (Optional)
     *                                     // - Defaults to undefined (falsey) to signal a local file which will be copied
     *                                     // - Specify true if this file is a remote file which will not to be copied
     *          "update": "delta"          // (Optional)
     *                                     //  - If not specified, this file will only be loaded once, and
     *                                     //    cached inside localStorage until this value is changed to either one below
     *                                     //  - "delta" to enable over-the-air delta update for this file
     *                                     //  - "full" means full update will be made when this file changes
     *
     *      }
     */
    "css": [
        {
            "path": "resources/css/app.css",
            "update": "delta"
        },
        {
            "path": "resources/css/custom.css",
            "update": "delta"
        }
    ],

    /**
     * Used to automatically generate cache.manifest (HTML 5 application cache manifest) file when you build
     */
    "appCache": {
        /**
         * List of items in the CACHE MANIFEST section
         */
        "cache": [
            "index.html"
        ],
        /**
         * List of items in the NETWORK section
         */
        "network": [
            "*"
        ],
        /**
         * List of items in the FALLBACK section
         */
        "fallback": []
    },

    /**
     * Extra resources to be copied along when build
     */
    "resources": [
        "resources/images",
        "resources/icons",
        "resources/startup"
    ],

    /**
     * File / directory name matchers to ignore when copying to the builds, must be valid regular expressions
     */
    "ignore": [
        "\.svn$"
    ],

    /**
     * Directory path to store all previous production builds. Note that the content generated inside this directory
     * must be kept intact for proper generation of deltas between updates
     */
    "archivePath": "archive",

    /**
     * List of package names to require for the cmd build process
     */
    "requires": [
    ],

    /**
     * Uniquely generated id for this application, used as prefix for localStorage keys.
     * Normally you should never change this value.
     */
    "id": "52d77512-9617-4982-b007-98bfaed1312e"
}
```

The contents of index.html are:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png" />
    <style type="text/css">
         /**
         * Example of an initial loading indicator.
         * It is recommended to keep this as minimal as possible to provide instant feedback
         * while other resources are still being loaded for the first time
         */
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #DB3040
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -15px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 30px;
            -webkit-animation-name: appLoadingIndicator;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation-direction: linear;
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator > * {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 30px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
            margin: 0 5px;
            width: 30px;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes appLoadingIndicator{
            0% {
                opacity: 0.8
            }
            50% {
                opacity: 0
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0.8
            }
        }
    </style>
    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src=".sencha/app/microloader/development.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="appLoadingIndicator">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error suggests that the `Ext.data` package is undefined.  How are you building your production code?

Comment: What is the content of your App.json file?

Comment: ok -all looks normal,what about content of index.html

Comment: Is that url with the dot correct `.sencha/app/microloader/development.js` ?

Comment: I believe so. It certainly corresponds to a real file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was that the `Ext` object was not in a global scope and thus not visible from the callback code. To fix it, I modified the minified app.js code in the following ways:

- Added '`MyApp=null;`' to the beginning of the file,
- Replaced '`var MyApp=MyApp||()`' with '`MyApp=MyApp||()`'.
- Replaced '`var Ext=Ext||()`' with '`Ext=Ext||()`'.

This placed the right stuff in the global namespace.